# Pivot table - calculations across totals

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

I have a Pivot table in Excel, where I have two fields in the totals area (say, I calculate the Countof both A and B).

Is it possible to do calculations on these totals instead of just displaying them side-by-side in the totals area, e.g. display CountOfA / CountOfB, or CountOfA as a % of CountOfB?

Answer (score 1):

A visual way to look at how pivot tables work is of a process where every part of the process can only act upon or refer to its left:

CELLS --> FILTERS and FORMULAS --> GROUPING RESULTS --> SCREEN

As you see, FORMULAS is on the left of GROUPING. You cannot create a formula or filter based on something that doesn't exist yet (a grouping result).

So, my first answer to your question is no.

However, some workarounds are possible! For example, you can do a second pivot table based on the result of the first. You can also add columns your original cells to include something that will let you do what you need (such as duplicating the total on every row). Sometimes a different approach is in order.

If you wish to explain your problem and data more in detail, we could try to look for a workaround solution for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Often I've created a second pivot table, or created formulas with reference to the first table, but I've found it cumbersome, and hoped there would be better solutions.

Comment: I agree. I hope Excel 2010 will facilitate that sort of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question, but have you tried to create a calculated field? In Excel 2007, choose Options, Tools, Formulas, Calculated Field and enter your formula.  Thus a new column is made.

Comment: A calculated field only lets you use fields from the original data set. The OP wants to use fields that are part of his pivot.